# Flutter/Firestore: Displaying gridtiles in categories

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

We are creating a recipe app for a school project.

We are using Dart/Flutter for the language and we have recipes stored in a Firestore DB collection called 'recipes' which have sub-collections of ingredients, comments and method. Inside the ingredients collection, there is a field called 'proteins' that contains an array of proteins (beef, pork, poultry, etc)

I have managed to make one big grid view which displays thumbnails of all the recipes currently stored in the DB, but we want to set them in categories by their proteins. I managed to make the individual lists for the categories but they each contain all of the recipes. I don't know now which direction to go to somehow search through the DB and then display them on the page.

This is the code for the current list that is being created.

I thought about somehow creating a search function that would create an array of document ID's which would be then used in the compiling of the lists, but not sure where to start

I'm just trying to get some nudge in the direction of how it would be done and not the code.  The process of it if you will.

Thanks in advance

```
          child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100.0,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 4,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    '${categories[index]}',//displays the protein name (beef
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 25.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 180.0,
                child: StreamBuilder(
                                stream: firestoreDb,
                                builder: (
                                  context,
                                  snapshot,
                                ) {
                                  if (!snapshot.hasData)
                                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                                  return ListView.builder(
                                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                      itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                                      itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                                        return GestureDetector(
                                          child: Card(
                                            elevation: 5,
                                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                            child: TestGridTile(
                                              snapshot: snapshot.data,
                                              index: index,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      });
                                }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )),
```

***EDIT*** TestGridTile code as requested

````
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:youth_food_movement/recipe/ui/ingredients_page.dart';

//card that displays the recipe information
class TestGridTile extends StatelessWidget {
  //snapshot of the database
  final QuerySnapshot snapshot;
  final int index;
  const TestGridTile({Key key, this.snapshot, this.index}) : super(key: key);
  static String idNumber;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //snaphot of the docs
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    var snapshotData = snapshot.docs[index];
    var docID = snapshot.docs[index].id;
    String recipeID = docID.toString();

    return Container(
      width: 150,//MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 150,//MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
      //get the image URL
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getImageURL(docID),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              //return the image and make it cover the container
              return GestureDetector(
                child: Image.network(
                  snapshot.data,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  idNumber = recipeID;
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                              IngredientsPage(recipeID)));
                },
              );
            } else {
              return Container(
                  child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ));
            }
          }),
    );
  }

  //method to get the image URL
  Future _getImageURL(var docID) async {
    //declare and instantiate the firebase storage bucket
    final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instanceFor(
        bucket: 'gs://youth-food-movement.appspot.com');
    //ref string will change so the parameter will be the jpg ID (maybe)
    String downloadURL =
        await storage.ref('recipe_images/$docID').getDownloadURL();
    return downloadURL;
  }
}```
I have attached an image of how it looks currently[![current image][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiaYi.jpg
````

Answer (score 0):

Because the `ingredience` is a `collection` we don't get it with the with the initial data. You have two options:

1. As it is now load all recipes and for each of them the ingrediences and for each category filter out the recipes that don't fit in it and show only those that do fit in. If you would share more code I could help you with it. What is behind `TestGridTile`.
2. Load for each category only the recipes that fin it by using a query with where clause and the `arrayContaines`. But for that the array `proteins` can't be nested in the `ingredience` subcollection of the collection you are filtering.

Both of the would be much easier if you would move the `proteines` array to the `doc` of the `recipes` collection. You could do that with the client side code or even with Firebase Cloud Functions.

Comment: Hi @Tarik, thanks for the reply. I've added the TestGridTile code as asked